# Even considering angular momentum conservation, is Newtonian mechanics the same as Lagrange mechanics?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, rotational-dynamics, angular-momentum

I heard that Lagrange mechanics can be derived from Newtonian mechanics, and Newtonian mechanics can be derived from Lagrange mechanics. I've heard many times that they have equal explanatory power. But I encountered that [there is a tricky point in deriving the law of conservation of angular momentum in Newtonian mechanics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/694229/).

On the other hand, theories that use the principle of least (or stationary) action derive each conservation law from the Noether's theorem by assuming each symmetry.

- So, is my understanding appropriate? *That is, while Newtonian mechanics itself derives conservation of linear momentum without any additional assumptions, and requires some manipulation to derive conservation of angular momentum, but Lagrangian mechanics cannot derive both without the assumption of symmetry, or derive both if the assumption is made.*
- Then, it seems that it can be explained by Lagrangian mechanics, but there is something that is not correct in Newtonian mechanics, or it seems that more assumptions are made in Newtonian mechanics than in Lagrange mechanics. *Which of the two makes sense?*

I'd also like to ask if Newton's third law conflicts with Lagrange mechanics, and if it's possible to find a set of Newtonian laws that have the same explanatory power as Lagrange mechanics. However, I want to know (even short) to just the above two questions.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/8903/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/292710/2451 and links therein.

Comment: As stated in the question, newtonian mechanics and lagrangian mechanics are interderivable, being equivalent formulations. General statement: a formulation is stated with explicit assumptions and implicit assumptions. In the end newtonian and lagrangian formulation work of the same set of assumptions, just to an extent shifted in what is stated explicitly versus implicitly.  In his book 'Principia' [Newton derived conservation of angular momentum](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/611110/17198) Implicit assumption: that the force that is acting between the two objects has *radial symmetry*.